# Cap'n Proto - How to compile the generated C++ file

Tags: c++, linux, g++, capnproto

I am new to Cap'n Proto and I was trying to compile the calculator example found here:
https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/master/c%2B%2B/samples/calculator.capnp

I used this command `capnp compile -oc++ calculator.capnp`  to generate the `calculator.capnp.c++` and `calculator.capnp.h` files.

I tried to compile the `calculator.capnp.c++` file using the following command: `g++ -o calc calculator.capnp.c++ -lcapnp -lkj -lcapnp-rpc -lkj-async` but I received this error message:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function '_start':
>   (.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I went over the official documentation and other resources, but I haven't found instructions on how to run this example (or anything similar). How can I proceed and run it?

Comment: Have you looked at the [full samples directory](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/tree/master/c%2B%2B/samples)? Especially the calculator [client](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/master/c%2B%2B/samples/calculator-client.c%2B%2B) and [server](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/master/c%2B%2B/samples/calculator-server.c%2B%2B) programs? Have you gone to [the main website](https://capnproto.org) to read its documentation?

Comment: Which "official documantation" and "other resources" did you check? Adding links to your question might be helpful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude To be fair, I can't see any instructions for building & running the samples. Though by examining the contents of the files we can deduce it!

Comment: _"Time-traveling RPC: Cap’n Proto features an RPC system that implements time travel such that call results are returned to the client before the request even arrives at the server!"_ lolwut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not building the *whole* sample, only the generated protocol files.

Notice how the repo also has `calculator-server.c++` and `calculator-client.c++`, both of which contain the `main` entrypoint function. Pick one and link it into your program.

If you use the CMakeLists.txt already provided, this is done for you.

Comment: Thank you, but since I am very new to this, I am not sure how to "use the CMakeLists.txt" file provided. I am also not sure how to "Pick one (of the `calculator-server.c++` and `calculator-client.c++` files) and link it into your program" as you have alternatively suggested. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: @LeenA I can't tell you anything that I haven't already, in this format. Only you can choose which sample you wish to build and run. The server, or the client? I can't decide for you. & if you aren't familiar with CMake, you can read their documentation.